# Timer on onDraw

Tags: android, eclipse, time

start button -> `game.class` -> `gameview.class` then loop again on `game.class` when player finish the 1st level it will call `gameview.class` to generate again the 2nd level. My problem is that my timer will also regenerate and restarts when going on the 2nd level. How can I make my timer pause and resume in this kind of flow of game?

on my Game.Class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
timeCounter = new TimeCounter();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    this.maze = (Maze) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (this.maze == null) {
        this.maze = (Maze) extras.get("maze");
    }
    gview = new GameView(this);
    gview.setTimeCounter(timeCounter);
    gview.setMaze(this.maze);
    setContentView(gview);
```

and on my GameView.Class:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
if (startTimer) {
        timeCounter.start();
        invalidate();
        int secondss = timeCounter.getTimeSeconds();
        String text = String.format("%02d:%02d", secondss / 60,
                secondss % 60);
        timer.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, (this.getWidth() - textBounds.right) - 5,
                (this.getHeight() - textBounds.bottom) - 5, timer);
    }
```

and when the 1st level finish it will call this method:

```
void shownextmaze() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Intent game = new Intent(context, Game.class);
    nextmaze = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    Maze maze = MazeCreator.getMaze(nextmaze);
    game.putExtra("maze", maze);
    context.startActivity(game);
    timeCounter.resume();

}
```

How can I make my timer run until the 4 levels are cleared?

Answer (score 1):

It is logical that onDraw will be called and timer will be start again. You should start your timer in a service and run it in background thread. Each time you want to access it value you can bind to service.

Check this [guideline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

In this code each time you open the app you will see updated value:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
        doBindService();

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mBoundService != null) {
                            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1))
                                    .setText(mBoundService.getValue() + "");
                        }
                    }
                });
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mBoundService = null;
                        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                MyService.class));
                        doUnbindService();
                    }
                });

    }

    private MyService mBoundService;
    private boolean mIsBound;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mBoundService = ((MyService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mBoundService
                    .getValue() + "");

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }
}
```

And a service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // private TimeCounter timeCounter;
    int x = 0;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    x++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Maybe you need activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Show Updated value" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Stop Service" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How can I do that? Can you share some sample codes on that sir @Misagh?

Comment: You mean you call only onDraw method to change level? So onCreate method is called once?

Comment: after 1st level is finish the method shownextmaze in GameView Class will call Game.Class then Game.class will call the GameView.Class where the onDraw method was drawn.

Comment: So I think there is no need for service. You can change startTimer to false in if(startTime) block and return it to true when you want to restart your timer.

Comment: the startTimer is initialize on GameView to true. So even if I set it to false on the startnextmaze method it ended up true when it loops back?